# Bath sink leaking from top side

Tags: leak, sink, bathroom-fixtures, caulking

I’ve a counter top bath sink and it’s leaking from the top side when not in use. I’ve checked the connections to the faucet and drainage pipes and there are no visible leaks, still tightened them a bit to try and resolve the issue, but it didn’t work. The caulking on the sink is a bit worn, but not sure why water would come out from the side to the counter-top even if the caulking is worn.

[image: Image of the leak from top side.]

It’s  not a matter of water spilling out based on usage pattern. The water comes out even during the night when the sink is not in use. Is there a way to identify the source of leak?

Comment: we cannot see what you see. Please attach a pic or 2.

Comment: The caulking is mainly to prevent water spilled on the countertop from getting in between the sink and counter.  If water is flowing out from the sink to the counter, then one your pipes is leaking, maybe a pin hole spraying the right way.

Comment: Could water be splashed out of the bowl when someone uses the sink and it is not cleaned up?  You assume the water is "leaking" from the bowl.

Comment: There is only one source of water - the taps.  If the sink is not in use at that time, then there is only one answer.  Pack different parts with paper tissue and see where it is coming from.